# JMeter higher connection time with non-GUI than with GUI mode

Tags: user-interface, jmeter

I did the same jmeter test in GUI and non-GUI mode on the same windows VM. All test configurations were the same, but the results were completely different. Connection time with non-GUI has become x10 higher. In addition,

```
 javax.net.ssl.SSLException, javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException, java.netSocketExceptions
```

errors appeared in a non-GUI mode.

Answer (score 0):

You failed to submit all requests due to sockets limit in your machine,

This was caused probably due to ignoring the [first best practice regarding resource requirement](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#lean_mean)

> suggestions on reducing resource usage.
>
> - Use CLI mode

CLI (non GUI) mode always will consume less resources

High resources GUI reduce resources available to produce significant load on SUT

Comment: @VladVlado it's not wrong, it just failed to submit all requests due to sockets limit in your machine